# Is a slackline, ratchet, and tree protector alone enough equipment to setup the slackline?

Tags: gear, slacklining

I'm new to slacklining and planning to buy a [slack line kit from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078BFWD6D)

With the rope and ratchet and tree protector which will be used on trees. Is this enough to be able to tie the rope between two trees and actually use the slackline or do I need more equipment like carabiners and slings, linelockers, rigging, rings, and pulleys?

What exactly do I need to slackline if I have two trees?

Comment: I personally wouldn't buy such a product from shady amazon vendors. There are numerous brick and mortar stores with online portals where knowledgeable employees can back their products with some kind of warranty and corporate responsiblity in case of defects. It won't be very much more expensive too.

Comment: Where do I find the directory of those vendors?

Comment: There is no directory, but in USA, [REI](https://www.rei.com/c/slacklines) has some, in Canada, [MEC](https://www.mec.ca/en/products/climbing/slacklines/c/1469), in Europe, [Decathlon](https://www.decathlon.fr/C-681381-slacklines). That's just from the top of my head. Try searching for outdoors retailers from your area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the question

> Is a slackline, ratchet, and tree protector alone enough equipment to setup the slackline?

The answer is **yes**, provided the kit is built for that purpose. In actuality, you could set it up without bark protectors, but that's frowned upon as it will hurt trees (some more than others).

Most kits are made to be setup in a similar way, which is shown below in a graphic from Gibbon Slacklines. Of course, it's possible to build a slackline with tubular webbing, rappel rings, carabiners and pulleys but it's usually something reserved for experienced climbers or rope riggers. It might look something like [in this post](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3102/how-do-i-tie-a-slackline-with-only-carabiners-and-webbing) (there are variations).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The description is one red flag for me, as it displays no knowledge about the product: It mixes general or over the top advertisement statements ("MAXIMUM SAFETY") with facts that have nothing to do with the advertised statement ("This is the best slackline for kids and beginners, with the 2-inch wide slackline webbing"). In short: Regardless of what it includes, I highly recommend against buying that set. You can get a beginners set from a well-known brand for ~50$ which isn't that much more than this.

Getting back to your specific question:

> What exactly do I need to slackline if I have two trees?

There is the obvious

- line (webbing)

and then two more "groups" of items: One for tensioning the line and the other for securing it at the ends. In a typical beginners set tensioning is done by a single

- ratchet

which has a webbing loop for attachment. Again typically a beginner line has a sewn loop at one end of the line, this means you can simply wrap that end around the tree and thread the line through the sewn loop to fixate it. Before doing that, put one of the

- 2x tree protection

on the tree. The other end of the line goes through the ratchet for tensioning. So what's left is to attach the ratchet to the second tree, which might not need any additional material if an attachment strip is already part of the ratchet. Otherwise you will need

- steel biner or shackle
- attachment strip
  (come in various forms, often quite heavy slings with a load-bearing inner part with an abrasion shield around)

where you put the strip around the tree over the protection and then connect the ratchet with the strip using the steel biner or shackle.

This is the minimum. If you don't have a loop in the line you need a second attachmnet strip and material for line-lockers and if you don't use a ratchet for tension there's various methods to do pulleys - none of this is beginner stuff though. If you don't use the entire length of the line you will after some time want to use another section of it, for which you do need one line lock. For that you need one steel biner and steel ring - just search for how to do a line lock and the material necessary is going to be evident.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your list. The type of product OP linked (even from brands like Gibbon) don't include biners or shackles. There's a gooseneck on the ratchet and on the main webbing so users can cinch around the tree without additional hardware like in [this image](https://www.feedthehabit.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/gibbon_slacklines-right-wrong1.jpg).

Comment: Why can't I just tie the rope onto the tree like it's a shoe lace? I agree that this answer sounds like overkill.

Comment: @Lasuiqw It is possible to make a slackline from scratch but it requires specific technical ropework knowledge. That's partly what imsodin was referencing.

Comment: I think I might have phrased the question to ask how to make a slackline from scratch but what I was really asking was whether that kit from Amazon was sufficient to just use out of the box. there's so images of slacklines that are hanged using different ways and I just wanted to know how the Amazon kit was going to work, whether it was self-sufficient and ready to go for use.

Comment: Ah right, my bad. In my first kit I got two attachment strips so never used the option displayed in that image as I thought it's "nicer" to my line. I'll remove those items from the list.